# how to catch a crash environment in intel pin?

Tags: exception, intel-pin

I'm learning intel pin now.
I wanna catch the crash env(registers),but I don't find any API on this after looking through the PIN's User Guide.

Checking each BBLs' eip before jump seems to be a solution to this,but is there any useful API could soulve this gracefully?
Thx a lot for any help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an exception handler.

```
typedef VOID(* LEVEL_PINCLIENT::CONTEXT_CHANGE_CALLBACK)(THREADID threadIndex, CONTEXT_CHANGE_REASON reason, const CONTEXT *from, CONTEXT *to, INT32 info, VOID *v)
```